# Unable to access current property of ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I'm trying to create a custom vertical scroll indicator, i.e. the vertical scrollbar will be hidden, and instead I will have up/down arrows appear if scrolling is available. My idea is to have a parent component where I create an useRef hook that hooks into a scrollable div. Then I pass the ref to a child component that will determine when to display the arrows based on the parent's ref.current.scrollHeight vs clientHeight. In the child component, I have a custom hook that takes in the ref and an object of triggers that determine when to remeasure the scrollHeight and clientHeight. I run into a type error where its trying to access the current property when ref is null. More details below. I'm never expecting the ref to be null, as it should be referencing a HTMLDivElement. How do I handle this null issue? Also, is my understanding of forwardRef correct? I'm expecting the child can access the parent ref's current properties. If not, then I guess this whole thing is moot.

The first section is my parent component. You can see on line 24 I have declared my ref as scrollContainerRef. It is referencing the div on line 31. The ref is also being passed into the OverflowIndication child component on line 39. **The lines are commented in the code**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { ReadInstanceITF } from '../../../interfaces/interface';
import ReadInstanceHeader from './ReadInstanceHeader';
import ReadInstanceReadEntry from './ReadInstanceReadEntry';
import OverflowIndication from './OverflowIndication';


interface ReadInstancePropsITF {
  readInstance: ReadInstanceITF;
  isEdit: boolean;
  editTimer: number;
  isExpanded: boolean;
  expandTimer: number;
  handleIsExpanded: Function;
  handleUpdateReaderBook: Function;
};

const ReadInstance = ({ readInstance, isEdit, editTimer, isExpanded, expandTimer, handleIsExpanded, handleUpdateReaderBook } : ReadInstancePropsITF) => {
  const readEntryList = readInstance.read_entry || [];
  const [ readEntrySelectToggle, setReadEntrySelectToggle ] = useState(false); //triggers overflow check whenever readEntry is clicked.
  const readEntryListAppendTimer = 500;
  const readEntrySelectTimer = 300;
  //***** line 24 below *****
  const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); 

  const handleReadEntrySelectToggle = useCallback(() => setReadEntrySelectToggle(readEntrySelectToggle => !readEntrySelectToggle), []);

  return (
    <div className='relative h-full w-full overflow-hidden'>
      //***** line 31 below *****
      <div ref={scrollContainerRef} className='h-full overflow-y-scroll scrollbar-hide'>

        <ReadInstanceHeader daysRead={readInstance.days_read} daysTotal={readInstance.days_total} isExpanded={isExpanded} expandTimer={expandTimer} handleIsExpanded={handleIsExpanded} />

        <ReadInstanceReadEntry readEntryList={readEntryList} readerBookId={readInstance.reader_book_id} readInstanceId={readInstance.ri_id} readEntryListAppendTimer={readEntryListAppendTimer} readEntrySelectTimer={readEntrySelectTimer } isEdit={isEdit} editTimer={editTimer} handleReadEntrySelectToggle={handleReadEntrySelectToggle} handleUpdateReaderBook={handleUpdateReaderBook} />

      </div>
        //***** line 39 below *****
      <OverflowIndication ref={scrollContainerRef} isEdit={isEdit} isExpanded={isExpanded} expandTimer={expandTimer} readEntryListLength={readEntryList.length} readEntryListAppendTimer={readEntryListAppendTimer} readEntrySelectToggle={readEntrySelectToggle} readEntrySelectTimer={readEntrySelectTimer} />


    </div>
  )
};

export default ReadInstance;
```

In the OverflowIndication child component, I believe forwardRef will allow access to the parent ref and I pass it to my custom hook useYOverflow on line 27.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import useYOverflow from '../../../hooks/useYOverflow';
import { BsChevronDown, BsChevronUp } from 'react-icons/bs';

interface OverflowIndicationPropsITF {
  isEdit: boolean;
  isExpanded: boolean;
  expandTimer: number;
  readEntryListLength: number;
  readEntryListAppendTimer: number;
  readEntrySelectToggle: boolean;
  readEntrySelectTimer: number;
};

const OverflowIndication = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, OverflowIndicationPropsITF>(({ isEdit, isExpanded, expandTimer, readEntryListLength, readEntryListAppendTimer, readEntrySelectToggle, readEntrySelectTimer }, ref) => {

  const overflowTriggers = {
    isEdit,
    isExpanded,
    expandTimer,
    readEntryListLength,
    readEntryListAppendTimer,
    readEntrySelectToggle,
    readEntrySelectTimer
  };
    //***** line 27 below *****
  const { refYOverflowing, refYScrollBegin, refYScrollEnd } = useYOverflow({ref, overflowTriggers});

  return (
    <div>
      {!refYScrollBegin && <BsChevronUp className='absolute w-full top-0' />}
      {!refYScrollEnd && refYOverflowing && <BsChevronDown className='absolute w-full bottom-0' />}
    </div>
  )
});

export default OverflowIndication;
```

My custom hook useYOverflow is where my typescript issues are appearing. I get this error when I try to access ref.current

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>'.
  Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void'.
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48WaT.png)

Below is useYOverflow hook. Only the first useEffect is relevant. The other useEffects are handling the rest of the remeasuring triggers.

```
import { useState, useEffect, RefObject, ForwardedRef } from "react";


interface useYOverflowITF {
  ref: RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  overflowTriggers: {
    isExpanded?: boolean;
    expandTimer?: number;
    readEntryListLength?: number;
    readEntryListAppendTimer?: number;
    readEntrySelectToggle?: boolean;
    readEntrySelectTimer?: number;
    isEdit?: boolean;
    newAuthorList?: string[];
    deleteAuthorList?: string[];
  };
}

interface useYOverflowReturnITF {
  refYOverflowing: boolean;
  refYScrollBegin: boolean;
  refYScrollEnd: boolean;
}

const useYOverflow = ({ref, overflowTriggers}: useYOverflowITF): useYOverflowReturnITF => {
    const [refYOverflowing, setRefYOverflowing] = useState(false);
    const [refYScrollBegin, setRefYScrollBegin] = useState(true);
    const [refYScrollEnd, setRefYScrollEnd] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!ref && !ref!.current) return
      const isYOverflowing = ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight;
      setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);

      const handleScroll = () => {
        const offsetBottom = ref?.current?.scrollHeight! - ref?.current?.clientHeight!;
        (ref?.current?.scrollTop! >= offsetBottom && refYScrollEnd === false) ? setRefYScrollEnd(true) : setRefYScrollEnd(false);
        (ref?.current?.scrollTop === 0) ? setRefYScrollBegin(true) : setRefYScrollBegin(false);
      }

      ref.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      return () => ref.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);

    //delay scroll height measurement until end of readInstance expand transition
    useEffect(() => {
      //need to add extra time to handle cases where scrollHeight is almost the height of the clientHeight.
      const expandTimer = overflowTriggers.expandTimer ? overflowTriggers.expandTimer + 100 : 0;
      const scrollHeightMeasureDelay = setTimeout(() => {
        const isYOverflowing = ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight || false;
        setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);
      }, expandTimer);

      return () => clearTimeout(scrollHeightMeasureDelay);
    }, [overflowTriggers.isExpanded]);

    //delay scroll height measurement until end of ReadEntry enter or exit transition
    useEffect(() => {
      const scrollHeightMeasureDelay = setTimeout(() => {
        const isYOverflowing = ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight || false;
        setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);
    }, overflowTriggers.readEntryListAppendTimer);

      return () => clearTimeout(scrollHeightMeasureDelay);
    }, [overflowTriggers.readEntryListLength]);

    //delay scroll height measurement until end of isReadEntrySelected transition
    useEffect(() => {
      const scrollHeightMeasureDelay = setTimeout(() => {
        const isYOverflowing = ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight || false;
        setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);
    }, overflowTriggers.readEntrySelectTimer);

    return () => clearTimeout(scrollHeightMeasureDelay);
  }, [overflowTriggers.readEntrySelectToggle]);

    //delay scroll height measurement in edge case: isExpand: true, isEdit: true, >= 8 readEntry with all Delete Containers open and then changing isEdit to false.
    useEffect(() => {
      const scrollHeightMeasureDelay = setTimeout(() => {
        const isYOverflowing = ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight || false;
        setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);
      }, overflowTriggers.readEntrySelectTimer);

      return () => clearTimeout(scrollHeightMeasureDelay);
    }, [overflowTriggers.isEdit]);

    //check overflow when adding or removing authors from CardBack.
    useEffect(() => {
      const isYOverflowing = ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight || false;
      setRefYOverflowing(isYOverflowing);
    }, [overflowTriggers.newAuthorList, overflowTriggers.deleteAuthorList])

    return { refYOverflowing, refYScrollBegin, refYScrollEnd };
}

export default useYOverflow;
```